# How to process character by character in a line

Tags: python, string, count

I have a file that has sequence on line 2 and variable called tokenizer, which give me an old position value. I am trying to find the new position.. For example tokenizer for this line give me position 12, which is E by counting letters only until 12. So i need to figure out the new position by counting dashes...

---------------LL---NE--HVKTHTEEK---PF-ICTVCR-KS----------

This is what i have so far it still doesn't work.

```
with open(filename) as f:
    countletter = 0
    countdash = 0
    for line, line2 in itertools.izip_longest(f, f, fillvalue=''):
        tokenizer=line.split()[4]
        print tokenizer

        for i,character in enumerate(line2):

            for countletter <= tokenizer:

                if character != '-': 
                    countletter += 1
                if character == '-':
                    countdash +=1
```

**my new position should be 32 for this example**

Comment: What does `for countletter <= tokenizer:` mean?

Comment: any reason you can't just iterate over the string? `for c in line2`

Comment: @GregHewgill the indent was wrong. but for count letter <= tokenizer.. i am trying to make the program count the  dashes, once the program count letter and reaches 12.. it should stop and tell me how many dashes it count.. but right now i have syntax error on <= i don't know why

Comment: I guess I'm just not following.  Which part doesn't work?

Comment: @Wug my original text looks like this and the position i was interested in was 12 which is 'E' LLNEHVKTHTEEKPFICTVCRKS. But since there is some change with additional dashes i have to consider those dashes and come up with new position. So i have to count the dashes before the original E in that sequence and add the count to 12 to get the final result

Comment: I'm only getting 30 for the new position... did you miscopy something somewhere?  12 digits plus 18 dashes  *EDIT* derp.  missed the final 2 dashes after the "NE"

Comment: yes it suppose to be 20 dashes before the position 12 (letter)..how would i do that using python

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14652/discussion-between-chad-d-and-wug)

Comment: I've posted an answer which might solve your problem.  Please review.

Comment: @pelson no this is not a homework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First answer, edited by Chad D to make it 1-indexed (but incorrect):

```
def get_new_index(string, char_index):
    chars = 0
    for i, char in enumerate(string):
        if char != '-':
            chars += 1
        if char_index == chars:
            return i+1
```

Rewritten version:

```
import re

def get(st, char_index):
    chars = -1
    for i, char in enumerate(st):
        if char != '-':
            chars += 1
        if char_index == chars:
            return i

def test():
    st = '---------------LL---NE--HVKTHTEEK---PF-ICTVCR-KS----------'
    initial = re.sub('-', '', st)
    for i, char in enumerate(initial):
        print i, char, st[get_1_indexed(st, i)]

def get_1_indexed(st, char_index):
    return 1 + get(st, char_index - 1)

def test_1_indexed():
    st = '---------------LL---NE--HVKTHTEEK---PF-ICTVCR-KS----------'
    initial = re.sub('-', '', st)
    for i, char in enumerate(initial):
        print i+1, char, st[get_1_indexed(st, i + 1) - 1]
```

Comment: This function returns the index of a dash character using the OP's provided string for inputs 0, 2, 4, 13, 15, and 21. use `print(string[get_new_index(string, char_index)])` to verify.  Also, you shouldn't use string as a variable name because it is the name of a built in module.

Comment: Also, this function will fail if you request the zeroth item in a string that begins with a letter.

Comment: All good points, Wug, thank you. Chad had edited my response to return i + 1 instead of return i, but even so, my answer was providing the character before the one it should provide. Initializing chars to -1 solved that issue.

Answer (score 0):

> my original text looks like this and the position i was interested in was 12 which is 'E'

Actually, it's K, assuming you're using zero indexed strings.  Python uses zero indexing so unless you're jumping through hoops to 1-index things (and you're not) it will give you K.  If you were running into issues, try addressing this.

Here's some code for you that does what you need it to (albeit with 0-indexing, not 1-indexing).  This can be found online [here](http://ideone.com/CyInQ):

```
def get_new_index(oldindex, str):
    newindex = 0

    for c in str:
        if c != '-':
            if oldindex == 0:
                return newindex
            oldindex -= 1
        newindex += 1

    return 1 / 0 # throw a shitfit if we don't find the index
```

Comment: Could you please tell me what is the idea behind your code. it works but I'm lost from retune  new index until return 1/0

Comment: Rather than keeping a count of the letters we have found and counting up until the count matches the number we were looking for, the number we were looking for is counted down until it reaches zero, at which point we have found the right number of letters.  the newindex variable tracks the total number of characters we have found (including dashes).

Comment: I found a bug on you code.. it wouldn't work on the index with that has dashes follow by the letter of that particular index

Comment: For example, given the same sequence(string) as above if the old index = 4, 15 ( or any old index that has dashes follow in this sequences) The program will run until it sees new letter.. so the count of new index is a bit off

Comment: It produces a zero indexed answer and expects a zero indexed input.  i.e. the first character in the string is the 'zeroth' character, the second is the 'oneth', etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is a silly way to get the second line, it would be clearer to use an islice, or `next(f)`

```
for line, line2 in itertools.izip_longest(f, f, fillvalue=''):
```

Here `count_letter` seems to be an `int` while `tokenizer` is a `str`. Probably not what you expect.

```
    for countletter <= tokenizer:
```

It's also a syntax error, so I think this isn't the code you are running

Perhaps you should have

```
tokenizer = int(line.split()[4])
```

to make `tokenizer` into an `int`

`print tokenizer` can be misleading because `int` and `str` look identical, so you see what you expect to see. Try `print repr(tokenizer)` instead when you are debugging.

once you make sure tokenizer is an int, you can change this line

```
    for i,character in enumerate(line2[:tokenizer]):
```

Comment: What would you do differently for >>for line, line2 in itertools.izip_longest(f, f, fillvalue=''): and thanks for advices

Comment: @ChadD, `line = next(f); line2 = next(f)` over two lines